# Vertically centering Font Awesome icon in link in div + link has strange clickable area

Tags: html, css, frontend

My goal is to vertically center a clickable (link) Font Awesome icon in a div-bar. It doens't work. Instead the icon sticks to the bottom of the div.

This is what I tried:

```css
#bar {
  background-color: red;
}

#bar>a {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#bar>a>svg {
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="bar">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </a>  
</div>
```

Also, how can the link be only the exact area of the symbol?

Comment: display:block to the SVG and remove the vertical align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `line-height` - because you have made your font size so big for the icon, it has increased the line-height also (and the line-height is udually larger than the font letters to allow for spacing between lines).

You can fix it by reducing the line height to match (or be less than) the height of the icon, e.g.:

```
#bar > a {
      font-size: 100px;
      line-height:75px;
      /* rest of CSS */
 }
```

**Working Snippet:**

```css
#bar {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #bar > a {
      font-size: 100px;
      color: white;
      background-color: green;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height:75px;

    }

    #bar > a > svg {
      background-color: blue;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>


<div id="bar">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `vertical-align:middle` from `#bar > a > svg` and you will be fine to go.also,clear the cache before loading pressing **ctrl+F5**.